# Write outlook 2007 add-in with visual studio 2013

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, visual-studio-2013

Is it posssible to write outlook 2007 add-in using visual studio 2013 in C#. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, the latest version of Visual Studio that can create an addin for Office 2007 is Visual Studio 2010.

If you want to develop an Office 2010 addin etc., you can use Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012.

If you want to develop an Office 2013 addin etc., you can only use Visual Studio 2013.

[Office Development and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This probably a bit late, but just for future reference: [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's no out of the box template for Office 2007 in Visual Studio 2013, but the addin will run fine in Office 2007.

Your project will have the Object Model for Office 2013 so while you can use it in previous versions of Office, you need to be careful not to call methods that aren't available in the earlier versions. For example in Outlook 2013 there is an inline reply so if you try to call that method in Outlook 2007 it will throw an exception.

If you're just looking to use the newer Visual Studio IDE for Office 2007 development then you can remove the 2013 Office references and add the 2007 references and you won't see any new methods as outlined above.

Edit: Not that you'd want to do this, but if you wanted to use the newer object model from 2007 without pulling in the interop library for 2013 you can actually call those newer methods dynamically and specify non existing delegate types by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, if anything it's pretty neat.